# How can I make a DIV disappear when clicked on it?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to make a div disappear when clicked like

http://www.b-r-u-n-o.it/bookstore/?src=st

Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('div').onclick = function() {
    this.style.display = 'none';
  };
};
```

```html
<div id="div">testing</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but I have a div with an image over it, and I can't see the text below. Do you have a solution for this? Thank btw

Comment: I was missing the z-index. Thank you!